# MantisConnect.php Error - Couldn't load from 'http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api/soap/mantisconnect.php' : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap, mantis

I am trying to get the status of issues from Mantis.  Having search through other posts here, people indicate that the web service on their site should be working.  However I get the error when attempting this. Openssl, SOAP, curl, etc... are all enabled in my PHP (5.4.26).

Sample code: (External Mantis works)

```
<?php
$SoapWSDLAddress = 'http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl';
$Client = new SoapClient($SoapWSDLAddress, array('trace' => true, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'soap_version' =>SOAP_1_2));
...
?>
```

Internal Site, which has MantisConnect installed that gets Exception.

```
<?php
$SoapWSDLAddress = 'http://192.168.0.1/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl';
$Client = new SoapClient($SoapWSDLAddress, array('trace' => true, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'soap_version' =>SOAP_1_2));
...
?>
```

I get an exception on the SoapClient call:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ' http://192.168.0.1/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://192.168.0.1/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl"
```

Going to the web address in my browser does show me the output for Mantis connect.

Comment: Is that leading space in the address necessary or is it a typo?

Comment: @GeorgeMarques Just noticed that as I was trying another address.  It is a typo, and correcting it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original code posting had a space before the http:// which caused the problem. Changing the code to remove the space fixed the error.

```
$SoapWSDLAddress = 'http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl';
$Client = new SoapClient($SoapWSDLAddress, array('trace' => true, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'soap_version' =>SOAP_1_2));
...
```